# Grafana InfluxDB Legend Alias as custom query

Tags: grafana, influxdb

Is it possible to transform the alias by in Grafana to map data? The measurement I have already includes the tag interface_name which translates to things like 'Bundle-Ether 1'. Then I have a variable query that pulls the interface description using that interface_name.

[image: interface description query var]

In the dashboard I have the following panel

[image: panel]

Which gives a legend of

[image: panel legend]

Is it possible to map the tag_interface_name to the interface_description? So that instead of Bundle-Ether1 on the legend I get the corresponding description

Bundle-Ether1 = 'Description'